# Why do some numbers in the call history have a share contact option but not others?

Tags: iphone, ios

If I tap on the (i) for numbers in the call history then some have Share Contact displayed as an option but others do not. 
None of the numbers are in the address book so why should there be any difference in the options available when the different numbers are selected?

For example here are two numbers in the call history:

[image]

The -0280 number has Share Contact and Share Location as an option, but -5420 does not. Instead it has Ignore Contact as an option which the previous number does not.
Why is there a difference?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify your question with a little more detail. For example, while you say neither is in your address book, is one of them in your contacts on another device / iCloud? Also, do you know if either of them is an iPhone user while the other isn't? Or perhaps one is set up with iCloud (and/or an Apple ID) while the other isn't? I appreciate you may not necessarily know the answers to these questions - just thinking out aloud as to what _may_ be relevant here.

Comment: @Monomeeth Yes, "Ignore Contact" only appears for unknown contacts that have iMessage and/or FaceTime associated with their number.

Comment: @Monomeeth. I don't know the all the circumstances except that there isn't an iCloud account set up for the phone receiving the calls, and nor for at least one of the incoming numbers.